# Can this background be achieved using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I wanted to created a div that has this complicated gradient as background.

I just want to know if this can be achieved using only CSS? It would be very helpful if you can give some example on how to do it.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This could use a combination of linear and radial gradients together, though it would likely be tough to achieve. Why not use an image background? See the following if you want to make it using CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient() and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient()

Comment: The image appears not to have any underlying mathematical pattern to it so although you can probably get close using gradients unless you can find the underlying pattern you'll never get an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect with a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()):

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #f3075c, #ed0077, #e11991, #cf30a8, #b643bd, #9860d9, #6f77ee, #288afa, #00a8ff, #00c2ff, #00d8f7, #51eceb);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Closest thing I can find is just a simple angled gradient, you can tweak the colours to look more like the real thing

```css
.gradient {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```